# Passing a textbox to a void

Tags: c#, textbox

I'm not sure if I'm using the wrong terminology so that may be why my searching has not turned up anything.

I have a bunch of text boxes that I want to validate and check that they don’t contain apostrophes. The code that I have is:

```
public void apostropheCheck(TextBox fieldName)
{
    Match m = Regex.Match(fieldName.Text, @"'");

    if (m.Success)
    {
        validationErrorProvider.SetError(fieldName, "Field can not contain apostrophes");
    }
    else if (!m.Success)
    {
        validationErrorProvider.SetError(fieldName, "");
    }
}
```

and the validation on the textbox is:

```
private void FirstNameTextBox_Validating(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    //Checks for apostrophes
    apostropheCheck(FirstNameTextBox);
}
```

However when I run this the value that gets passed to the void is the text that is in the text box (e.g ‘John’ or ‘Mary’) I could get this to work just using the code that’s in the void for each validation event but that would be repeating myself a lot. Is there a better way?

Comment: Could you rephrase what you mean by "passing to a void?"  That really makes no sense to me at all and I can't see any other way to interpret what you mean that could make sense.

Comment: I think you may have your terms mixed up.  A void is a type.  It doesn't make sense to pass anything to it.  Perhaps you mean a function?  In which case, you mention two such functions in your post.  Which one are you referring to?

Comment: What you call `void` is actually called a `method`. `void` only indicates that the `method` does not return any value.

Comment: Thanks to all who corrected my terminology (I’m just learning and while I know what I want to do, I don’t always know what it’s called or how to express it.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sender object of the event is a TextBox, so you can cast it to a text box and repeat the same event handler for all of the text boxes in your application

```
private void FirstNameTextBox_Validating(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    apostropheCheck(((TextBox)sender).Text);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I think I think in this case this is the answer I needed, while having one validation event is a good idea some of the textboxes get validated for other things first and only check for apostrophes if there are no errors with other things (and if the apostrophe check ran second it would wipe out the error from the first and vice versa).

Answer (score 3):

You can have one common handler and use that for all of the textboxes' `Validating` event.

```
private void CommonTextBox_Validating(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    //Checks for apostrophes
    apostropheCheck((TextBox)sender);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Terminology: you are referring to your function `apostropheCheck` as the void which is its return type the standard way is to use the function name apostropheCheck.
2. All of you text boxes can be validated using the same function if you replace the name of the text box in the code with sender ex.

```
    private void FirstNameTextBox_Validating(object sender,System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        //Checks for apostrophes
            apostropheCheck((TextBox)sender);
    }
```